# Aaccess Denied - java.net.SocketPermission on JNLP

Tags: java, javafx, jnlp

I'm working on JavaFx, and we need to run our app on JNLP Web Start, we have faced some problem, and we solved them, now, we have an error in `SocketPermission` on JNLP runtime.

My problem happens when I call an HTTP request to our server(APIs), the App can't call the request due the permission is denied :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.1.16:8080" "connect,resolve")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
```

Some Developers said I should have change the `java.policy` file in my JRE, and said it's wrong way to solve it, but i did this way and nothing happened.

Is there other ways to solve this problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

Add the below section to your JNLP file:

```xml
  <security>
      <all-permissions/>   
  </security>
```

Comment: Note that recently, the manifest of the Jar must also specify `all-permissions`. And be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is there any documentation or tutorial for JaNeLA ?! In Drive, I found there any many Jar files, how can i call them ?!

Comment: *"n Drive, I found there any many Jar files, how can i call them ?!"* It's the one named `janela.jar`. The reason I did not link directly to it is that then you just get a large, mostly dark screen saying it can't show a preview and 'do you want to download. If you scroll down the directory and select the Jar, it will show a very short blurb. But don't expect much in the way of documentation, it was written a few years ago and won't be updated.

Comment: I tried your app, and thank you.

But i got this error
`cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'context' is not allowed to appear in element 'jnlp'.`
What's that mean ?!